Fitting a logistic model with multiple dependent vars/LHS
Is there a way to do multivariate logistic regression using glm()? I have several binary outcomes and I know you can do this with linear regression (lm()) and cbind() but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with glm() and cbind()
library(tidyverse)

lm(cbind(mpg, cyl, disp) ~ hp + drat + wt + qsec, data = mtcars) %>% 
  broom::tidy(conf.int = T)

This returns a tidy tibble with your outcomes (mpg, cyl, disp). How can I extend this to logistic regression.
df <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(c(vs, am), factor))

glm(cbind(am, vs) ~ hp + drat + wt + qsec, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df) %>% 
  broom::tidy()

I know this isn't the best dataset to use (probably due to complete separation) but cbind just returns an unexpected output than if you ran the glms separately.
glm(am ~ hp + drat + wt + qsec, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df) %>% 
  broom::tidy()

glm(vs ~ hp + drat + wt + qsec, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df) %>% 
  broom::tidy()


look for multinomial fitting, e.g. ?nnet::multinom

@BenBolker it seems OP is not interested in MNL but rather just have the same predictors but different response variables. ie 2 distinct glms but with the same predictors

To clarify, I am not interested in MNL. As Onyambu and @GRowInG correctly point out, I am interested in doing binary_outcome_1 ~ predictors, binary_outcome_2 ~ predictors, binary_outcome_3 ~ predictors etc

Have a look at
glm(cbind(am, vs) ~ hp + drat + wt + qsec, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df, method = "model.frame") %>% 
broom::tidy()

which returns

# A tibble: 5 × 13
  column            n   mean     sd median trimmed    mad   min    max  range  skew kurtosis      se
  <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 cbind(am, vs)    64   1.42  0.498   1       1.40  0      1      2      1    0.316     1.10  0.0622
2 hp               32 147.   68.6   123     141.   52     52    335    283    0.761     3.05 12.1   
3 drat             32   3.60  0.535   3.70    3.58  0.475  2.76   4.93   2.17 0.279     2.44  0.0945
4 wt               32   3.22  0.978   3.32    3.15  0.517  1.51   5.42   3.91 0.444     3.17  0.173 
5 qsec             32  17.8   1.79   17.7    17.8   0.955 14.5   22.9    8.4  0.387     3.55  0.316

In the first line of results in the output above, you can see that glm seems to interpret cbind(am, vs) as a combined dependent variable of am and vs having multiple categories and not being dichotomous (in this example 0 or 1). This kind of dependent variable would require multinomial logistic regression as pointed out by Ben Bolker.
As you mentioned, if you run seperate glm models with one dependent variable at a time, you get different results and warning messages regarding complete separation as well as fitted probabilities having values (very close to) 0 or 1.
If you would like to run the two glm models in one go and present results in a single object, we can use purrr:map as shown here which results in the following approach:
#--------------
# Load packages
#--------------
library(tidyverse)

#--------------
# Define data, including independent variables & dependent variables
#--------------
df <- mtcars
independent.variables.formula <- "~ hp + drat + wt + qsec"
dependent.variables <- c("am", "vs")

#--------------
# create output for both models in a data.frame showing the results
#--------------
df_res <- map(dependent.variables, function(DV) {
  paste(DV, independent.variables.formula) %>% 
    as.formula %>% 
    glm(family=binomial(link = "logit"), data = df) %>%
    broom::tidy(conf.int = T)
}) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  as.data.frame () %>%
  mutate (DV = c(rep ("am", 5), rep ("vs", 5)),
          across(c(2:4, 6:7), .fns = function(x) {format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2)})) %>%
  relocate (DV, .before = term)

df_res[ ,6] <- format.pval(df_res[ ,6], eps = .001, digits = 3) # format small p-values < 0.001 nicely

df_res

  DV        term estimate  std.error statistic p.value   conf.low conf.high
1  am (Intercept)   206.22 1166788.76      0.00   1.000         NA 238011.23
2  am          hp     0.24     687.34      0.00   1.000    -139.85        NA
3  am        drat   103.37  132242.73      0.00   0.999  -10359.33  12068.44
4  am          wt   -94.56   84508.03      0.00   0.999  -54340.19  14115.43
5  am        qsec   -20.03   34601.06      0.00   1.000   -3473.64   3149.50
6  vs (Intercept) -1928.91 1845493.29      0.00   0.999 -124797.75 120939.92
7  vs          hp     1.59    2408.34      0.00   0.999    -489.26        NA
8  vs        drat    92.35  139959.57      0.00   0.999  -16047.24  16231.94
9  vs          wt   -82.30   77899.01      0.00   0.999   -5580.25   4963.40
10 vs        qsec    91.59   75674.95      0.00   0.999   -3734.28   4115.71



I think your first example is not doing at all what I would have expected the OP to want, and possibly not what you think.  Why have you included method = "model.frame" ? (to be more explicit, the first glm() call is creating a model frame, not fitting a GLM ...)

@BenBolker The first part of my answer is supposed to explain why the results are different from what the OP expects to find. I also do not think that the question is about MNL, but we'll hopefully find out if that assumption is correct.

Thank you so much! Your solution worked although its a shame cbind() does all the hard work within lm(), but not for glm(). I hope it's okay I simplified your code!
df_res <- map(dependent.variables, function(DV) {
paste(DV, independent.variables.formula) %>%
as.formula %>%
glm(family=binomial(link = "logit"), data = df) %>%
broom::tidy(conf.int = T) %>% 
mutate(dv = DV,
       signif = gtools::stars.pval(p.value),
       across(where(is.numeric), round, 5)
       )%>% 
relocate(dv, .before = term)

}) %>%
bind_rows()

This also works and helps me think about how to map it. df_res2 <- map(dependent.variables, function(DV) {
glm(
formula = as.formula(paste(DV, independent.variables.formula)),
family=binomial(link = "logit"),
data = df
) %>%
broom::tidy(conf.int = T) %>%
mutate(dv = DV,
signif = gtools::stars.pval(p.value),
across(where(is.numeric), round, 5)
)%>%
relocate(dv, .before = term)
}) %>%
bind_rows()
